# Cryptic crossword clue: It detailed visually challenged rodents (7,5)

Tags: cryptic-clues

Does anyone have any idea what the answer to this could be?

> **It detailed visually challenged rodents (7,5)**

Comment: Consider accepting the answer by clicking on the checkmark right next to it.

Answer (score 21):

It's a

> CARVING KNIFE.

The visually challenged rodents are

> [three blind mice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Blind_Mice) - according to the nursery rhyme, they got their tails chopped off (de-tailed) by a carving knife.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is a proper cryptic, though. (what's the def?)

Comment: @Rubio The def is "It"... Still odd though.

Comment: This seems like a "cryptic definition" clue, which doesn't have a straightforward definition like other clue types (e.g. hidden words). I think the compiler should have indicated this with a question mark, which is convention for clues of this type, I think...

Comment: There's no particular convention for question marks on cryptic definitions in Britain, at least. I would say normally a clue like this would go for a bit more misdirection though. Here you have to realise that "detailed" should be understood as "de-tailed", but "visually challenged rodents" isn't a misleading way of saying "blind mice", just a rather long-winded one